# How to edit a large csv file field?

Tags: excel, csv, weka

I have a large csv file and the data in file is required for clustering using weka. In some columns, the numbers include * symbol, like 45.8* . How can I edit the file to get rid of those stars from the whole column, before converting to .arff. (2 cols specifically) Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only have to do this once, how about using **Find and Replace**? Enter the tilde (`~`) because the `*` has special meaning in Find/Replace.

[image]

[image]

If you need to do this multiple times, you could write a VBA macro that automates this, or just use the Macro Recorder to generate a macro for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to remove all of the `*` from a file you can use [Regular Expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression).  They can help you find and remove certain characters or patterns.